# Symfony - Propel - Value is not an integer

Tags: symfony1, propel

in my schema I set the size:

size:          { type: bigint, required: true }

My generated 'base' model gives me:

```
public function setSize($v)
{
    if ($v !== null) {
        $v = (string) $v;
    }

    if ($this->size !== $v) {
        $this->size = $v;
        $this->modifiedColumns[] = TorrentPeer::SIZE;
    }

    return $this;
} // setSize()
```

Why does it case it to a string and not an integer?

I now receive the error:

```
"7818435653" is not an integer.
```

I tried changing the (string) to (int), but it did not work, I receive the same error. I'm confused why Propel made this value string when I specified bigint. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

propel stores bigint as a string as PHP's integer type is too small: http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.5/Schema#NumericTypes

Comment: Thanks for the link. do you suggest I make my bigint columns rather strings?

Comment: No. You didn't mention where the exception is thrown. Probably you'll need some manual type casting before saving and after retrieving your data.